# Professor reviews proposal as a favor, should I send a reminder

Tags: etiquette, email

I am applying for PhD, and in the application I am required to write a research proposal.

I asked my thesis supervisor to write a recommendation for me, and he agreed,but he told me that I need to work more on my writing and carefully write my research proposal. He told me to have people read for me before submitting it and suggested that I send it to him so he can review it for me as a favor.

I got his email with feedback on the proposal. In the email he wrote "Here is my first feedback." We discussed the review he made and I made changes and he asked me to send him the new proposal. After I sent the email, he told me that he will read it and give me another feedback that same night. That was about five days ago and now he is on a vacation.

Would it be appropriate to remind him ? I need his feedback because I am trying to submit the application. Should I just submit the application and just assume that he is too busy for me ? I don't want to be naggy and annoying. After all, he is doing me a favor.

Comment: You are seeking an advice on how to communicate with your thesis supervisor. The only one who knows the guy here and is you.

Comment: The fact the he left on holiday with this proposal due for submission speaks loudly as to how seriously he's taking it. I think you are showing far too much deference here. It's *your* PhD, not his. You must (morally and practically) take a lead here. If there are reasons why especial regard is to be made to this or any professor, please state them. Also state any assessment or concern of your own that is making you so deferential to the professor in this matter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Send an email suggesting you don't assume he will offer any more help, but leaving the door open in case he offers some:

> Thanks so much for your help with my proposal. I believe your suggestions have really improved it. Attached is my current version; I will submit it tomorrow evening. Let me know if you have any last-minute suggestions before then.

Comment: Thank a lot. Smart and simple. I will do that. If I don't hear from him I will proceed and submit.